# Why am I not able to write to a remote Realm object server?

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform

When I execute the following code, with the Realm object server running on my mac, it inserts values correctly. But when I deploy the object server the `items.insert` line is never executed:

```
try! items.realm?.write {
 items.insert(Task(value: ["text": text]), at: items.filter("completed = false").count)
}
```

I tried to separate the code into a try catch block but no errors are generated / caught.

How should I debug this? Is there something 'wrong' with my ROS Ubuntu setup?

Comment: Have you upgraded from one version to another recently?

Comment: I think I might have. I definitely upgraded Xcode to 8.1 beta

Comment: I actually meant on the server side---the version of the server.

Comment: Brand new to all this. So it was the standard ubuntu 16.04 droplet with the latest realm server added